# In Web services, what is difference between Endpoint and Remote Gateway

Tags: web-services, terminology, definition, endpoint, gateway

I goggled but I cannot determined what are the difference between endpoint and gateway. Based on their definition, they seems alike.

[Description of Endpoint](http://www.bentley.com/en-US/Products/Web+Service+Gateway/)

> What is Web Service Gateway? Web Service Gateway is a server-side
>   application that opens a communication channel between Bentley’s Apps
>   for mobile devices and Bentley’s project information management
>   systems.

[Description of Web Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/Initialization2.html)

> Web services expose one or more endpoints to which messages can be
>   sent. A web service endpoint is an entity, processor, or resource that
>   can be referenced and to which web services messages can be addressed.
>   Endpoint references convey the information needed to address a web
>   service endpoint. Clients need to know this information before they
>   can access a service.

Answer (score 10):

**Endpoint:**

The endpoint is a connection point where HTML files or active server pages are exposed. **Endpoint is the URL where your service can be accessed by a client application.** The same web service can have multiple endpoints. An end point indicates a specific location for accessing a service using a specific protocol and data format.

**GateWay:**

An **service Gateway provides a central access point** for managing, monitoring, and securing access to your publicly exposed web services. It would also allow you to consolidate services across disparate endpoints as if they were all coming from a single host. **A service gateway encapsulates all the details of accessing the service** into a single component and hides the component behind an interface that has no direct dependencies on the underlying communications channel.